# Specific Rails env variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The Rails application at production have file `shared/.env.production` The content like this:

```
DB_NAME=db
DB_PASSWORD=pass
```

What is the gem which process this file? Where I can read about such conventions? How to setup this at development?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) gem for that. Create a symlink of `shared/.env.production` inside the current release folder. Maybe, you don't need the extra suffix `.production`. However, if you want that for some reason, you have to manually load the `.env.production` using `Dotenv.load('.env.production')` once before your server starts. If you are using Unicorn, you can put something like below in your `unicorn.rb`.

```
after_fork do |server, worker|
  Dotenv.overload("#{Rails.root}/.env.production")
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection 
end
```

If you are using Capistrano and want Capistrano to create the symlink for you, add the file in the list of `linked_files` as:

`set :linked_files, %w{.env.production}`

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) (via the [dotenv-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/dotenv-rails) gem).

I believe that gem usually has you place the `.env` files in the root though, not a `shared` folder.